# Repeated measures ANOVA and link to mixed-effect models in R

Tags: r, statistics, anova

I have a problem when performing a two-way rm ANOVA in R on the following data (link : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1nIlFfijUm4Ib6TJoHUUNeEJnZnnNzO29):

[subjectnbr is the id of the subject and blockType and linesTTL are the independent variables. RT2 is the dependent variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PW1Ya.png)

I first performed the rm ANOVA through using ezANOVA with the following code:

```
ANOVA_RTS <- ezANOVA(
    data=castRTs
    , dv=RT2
    , wid=subjectnbr
    , within = .(blockType,linesTTL)
    , type = 2
    , detailed = TRUE
    , return_aov = FALSE
)
ANOVA_RTS
```

The result is correct (I double-checked using statistica).

However, when I perform the rm ANOVA using the lme function, I do not get the same answer and I have no clue why.

There is my code:

```
lmeRTs <- lme(
      RT2 ~ blockType*linesTTL, 
      random = ~1|subjectnbr/blockType/linesTTL, 
      data=castRTs)

anova(lmeRTs)
```

Here are [the outputs of both ezANOVA and lme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfH2J.png).

I hope I have been clear enough and have given you all the information needed.

I'm looking forward for your help as I am trying to figure it out for at least 4 hours!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your description of the problem is almost perfect. The only missing thing is the data. The first 15 lines are not enough to be able to reproduce your problem. Could you try designing a minimal instance of your problem, with a small dataset that you would include in your question? It may even help you understand what's wrong. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for guidelines on how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. Hope this helps ;-)

Comment: Yes, please include sample data and expected output from `ezANOVA`. I think the issue is with your random effect specification in `lme`, where you need to take into account that the random effects `blockType:subjectnbr` and `linesTTL:subjectnbr` are crossed. Those 2-factor random effect models can be quite tricky to specify in `lme`. To give more specific help we need a reproducible example with data.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your comments. 
Here is a link with my data: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1nIlFfijUm4Ib6TJoHUUNeEJnZnnNzO29

Cheers :)

Comment: @user9935785 I've added an answer showing how to reproduce the `ezANOVA` result with `nlme::lme`. I've also slightly changed your question title to better reflect the problem statement in the main body of your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a step-by-step example on how to reproduce `ezANOVA` results with `nlme::lme`.

#### The data

We read in the data and ensure that all categorical variables are `factor`s.

```
# Read in data
library(tidyverse);
df <- read.csv("castRTs.csv");
df <- df %>%
    mutate(
        blockType = factor(blockType),
        linesTTL = factor(linesTTL));
```

#### Results from `ezANOVA`

As a check, we reproduce the `ez::ezANOVA` results.

```
## ANOVA using ez::ezANOVA
library(ez);
model1 <- ezANOVA(
    data = df,
    dv = RT2,
    wid = subjectnbr,
    within = .(blockType, linesTTL),
    type = 2,
    detailed = TRUE,
    return_aov = FALSE);
model1;
#        $ANOVA
#              Effect DFn DFd          SSn       SSd           F            p
#1        (Intercept)   1  13 2047405.6654 34886.767 762.9332235 6.260010e-13
#2          blockType   1  13     236.5412  5011.442   0.6136028 4.474711e-01
#3           linesTTL   1  13    6584.7222  7294.620  11.7348665 4.514589e-03
#4 blockType:linesTTL   1  13    1019.1854  2521.860   5.2538251 3.922784e-02
#  p<.05         ges
#1     * 0.976293831
#2       0.004735442
#3     * 0.116958989
#4     * 0.020088855
```

#### Results from `nlme::lme`

We now run `nlme::lme`

```
## ANOVA using nlme::lme
library(nlme);
model2 <- anova(lme(
    RT2 ~ blockType * linesTTL,
    random = list(subjectnbr = pdBlocked(list(~1, pdIdent(~blockType - 1), pdIdent(~linesTTL - 1)))),
    data = df))
model2;
#                   numDF denDF  F-value p-value
#(Intercept)            1    39 762.9332  <.0001
#blockType              1    39   0.6136  0.4382
#linesTTL               1    39  11.7349  0.0015
#blockType:linesTTL     1    39   5.2538  0.0274
```

#### Results/conclusion

We can see that the F test results from both methods are identical. The somewhat complicated structure of the `random` effect definition in `lme` arises from the fact that you have *two* crossed random effects. Here "crossed" means that for every combination of `blockType` and `linesTTL` there exists an observation for every `subjectnbr`.

#### Some additional (optional) details

To understand the role of `pdBlocked` and `pdIdent` we need to take a look at the corresponding two-level mixed effect model

[image]

The predictor variables [image] are your categorical variables `blockType` and `linesTTL`, which are generally encoded using dummy variables.

The variance-covariance matrix for the random effects [image] can take different forms, depending on the underlying correlation structure of your random effect coefficients. To be consistent with the assumptions of a two-level repeated measure ANOVA, we must specify a block-diagonal variance-covariance matrix `pdBlocked`, where we create diagonal blocks for the offset `~1`, and for the categorical predictor variables `blockType` `pdIdent(~blockType - 1)` and `linesTTL` `pdIdent(~linesTTL - 1)`, respectively. Note that we need to subtract the offset from the last two blocks (since we've already accounted for the offset).

**Some relevant/interesting resources**

[Pinheiro and Bates, Mixed-Effects Models in S and S-PLUS, Springer (2000)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1441903178)

[Potvin and Schutz, Statistical power for the two-factor
repeated measures ANOVA, Behavior Research Methods, Instruments & Computers, 32, 347-356 (2000)](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.3758/BF03207805.pdf)

[Deming Mi, How to understand and apply
mixed-effect models, Department of Biostatistics, Vanderbilt university](http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/pub/Main/DemingMi/2007-04-27.pdf)